# Finding plate candidate with diffrent methods

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, detection

I want to detect license plate candidates using diffrent methods, yet I'm stuck after trying several times.
I wonder if my approach is correct.
**I'm working with HSV image model.**
My approach for known methods so far.
 1. Preprocessed image -> morphological transformation -> blob detection.
 2. Preprocessed image -> edge detection -> finding rectangles in image.
 3. Preprocessed image -> edge detection -> histogram projection -> histogram analysis

I don't want to focus on method 3 as somebody else is working on it.
Should I use connected component analysis somewhere?
I'm using BlackHat and TopHat operations with gaussian blurring and adaptive thresholding for image preprocessing.
Here is my code:

```
imgHSV = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 3), np.uint8)
imgHSV = cv.cvtColor(self.image, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
_, _, self.imgValue = cv.split(imgHSV)
imgTopHat = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 1), np.uint8)
imgBlackHat = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 1), np.uint8)

structuringElement = cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT, (3, 3))

imgTopHat = cv.morphologyEx(self.imgValue, cv.MORPH_TOPHAT, structuringElement)
imgBlackHat = cv.morphologyEx(self.imgValue, cv.MORPH_BLACKHAT, structuringElement)
imgGrayscalePlusTopHat = cv.add(self.imgValue, imgTopHat)
imgGrayscaleHSV = cv.subtract(imgGrayscalePlusTopHat, imgBlackHat)

imgBlurred = np.zeros((self.height, self.width, 1), np.uint8)
imgBlurred = cv.GaussianBlur(imgGrayscaleHSV, GAUSSIAN_SMOOTH_FILTER_SIZE, 0)
thresholdedImage = cv.adaptiveThreshold(imgBlurred, 255.0, cv.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_BLOCK_SIZE, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_WEIGHT)
```

By preprocessed image I mean image after extracting Value, performing TopHat and BlackHat operations, gaussian blurring and adaptive thresholding. 
I tried with finding simpleBlob using openCV but it doesn't work properly with prepared image.
As for edge detection I'm using canny edge detection and have implemented sobel edge detection.

Example processed image(I don't have enough reputation to post images yet...)

[image]

I expect output to be image with contours of potential plate candidates but I can't get properly transformed image to work with. What should I do? How should transformations(and what type) be applied.

Answer (score 0):

I tried using different methods for plate detection: 2 and 3. They are don't  working in practically.

The best methods - ML based. For example the simplest on [HAAR cascades](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_russian_plate_number.xml). HOG + SVM works better. And DNN based approaches are the best - [from Intel](https://github.com/opencv/open_model_zoo/tree/2018/intel_models/license-plate-recognition-barrier-0001) [with advance information](https://software.intel.com/en-us/openvino-toolkit/documentation/pretrained-models) (you can use it with opencv_dnn with OpenVINO inference engine).

Do not waste time on manual algorithms.